# Вывести get_tags() исключая метки текущего поста

Tags: wordpress

Под постом нужно вывести все метки, но исключить метки самого поста.
Делаю так:

```html
<?php

foreach ( $tags as $tag) {
  $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
        
 if (!in_array($tag->term_id, $exclude)) {
        
 echo '<div>
          <a href="' . $tag_link . '">
          <h5>'. $tag->name .'</h5>
        </a>
      </div>';
          
 }
}

?>
```

Не пойму как сформировать переменную $exclude, в которую нужно добавить ID для исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Пока ждал ответ, сам додумался:

```html
<?php
$tags = get_tags();

$exclude = [];
$post_tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
foreach ( $post_tags as $tag ) {
  $exclude[] = $tag->term_id;
}

foreach ( $tags as $tag) {
  $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
        
 if (!in_array($tag->term_id, $exclude)) {
        
 echo '<div>
          <a href="' . $tag_link . '">
          <h5>'. $tag->name .'</h5>
        </a>
      </div>';
          
 }
}

?>
```